# why do we treat normal distribution in D dimensions as a sphere?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

In bishop's book,the author mentioned that the integral of the multidimentional normal function goes to 0 since the sphere volume's goes to 0.
How can i intuitively see this?

Comment: Please provide the _exact_ statement that you found in Bishop's book (including the full title, page number etc will also help).  As stated in your question, what _you claim_ the author "mentioned" makes no sense whatsoever.